# dynamically update ruby method in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Im looking for a way to update a ruby method that gets images from the database, without having to reload the page. I have a HTML multiselect dropdown menu from semanti-ui and based on the selections in the dropdown alter the request to the model. Below is a cut-to-size version of the page i'm working on. Any ideas on how best to tackle this would be greatly appreciated

```
<select multiple="" name="skills" class="ui fluid normal dropdown form-control">
  <option value='option1'>option1</option>
  <option value='option2'>option2</option>
  <option value='option3'>option3</option>
</select>

<% @pictures.where(category:[DROPDOWN SELECTIONS HERE]).each do |data|%>
  <%= image_tag data.link, :data => { :caption => data.title} %>
<% end %>

<script>
  $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to misunderstand how client-server inter-cooperation works. Ruby embedded code is run *before* the page is sent to server, producing the pure html/js content. You might check what the page content is received by the browser by examining the page source code. There won’t be any trace of embedded ruby.

The only way to accomplish this task is to use js to perform AJAX request to the specifically dedicated server endpoint, that will return the JSON-collection based on incoming request parameters and *re-render* the response from this AJAX call with pure javascript on the client side.